# Use OsmAnd for navigation in AutoMate Car Dashboard app

Tags: applications, osmand

I'm using [AutoMate - Car Dashboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitspice.automate)? This app is similar to Android Auto, the feature I'm looking for is the ability to use OsmAnd's navigation instead of Google's (Android Auto, from Google tied navigation to Google Maps).

Tried to search on the net on how to use/connect to the car's computer, but only saw videos on YouTube showing how to use it. When I connect my phone (with AutoMate installed), the car's computer can't see it, and the only option is to use Android Auto.

Does anyone have any input/tips on how to make it work?